# Как в QTableView добавить ссылку на файл?

Tags: c++, qt, url, table

Возможно в ячейку добавить несколько ссылок на файлы? Допустим я QFileDialog выбираю несколько файлов и по нажатию добавить строку в таблицу, в ячейке таблицы появляются ссылки на выбранные файлы.

Comment: Что именно понимается под ссылками на файлы? Пути, пиктограммы, вложение как в почте?

Comment: @tequillaz Рабочая ссылка на файл. Чтоб по клику открывался сам файл, программами которые установлены на компьютере. Такое вообще возможно сделать ? QTabelView поддерживает HTML / я так понял чтоб отображались ссылки как ссылки надо использовать ItemDelegate. И самое близкое к теме я нашел тут, но это не совсем то https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397943/how-to-make-a-fast-qtableview-with-html-formatted-and-clickable-cells

Comment: Не удастся реализовать такое поведение без модификации представления. Тут два варианта реализации, первый - отказ от QTableView в пользу QTableWidget и назначение специального виджета для отображения подобных ссылок там где надо. Второй - как описано в статье

Comment: Почему не получится? Стандартный делегат реализует двустороннее взаимодействие с пользователем только в момент редактирования данных; когда редактирование данных не происходит, делегат только отображает данные, средства для  взаимодействия с пользовательским вводом отсутствуют. Так устроено стандартное API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы нарисовать ссылку в `QTableView`:

```
void CHtmlDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter,
                          const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                          const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItemV4 opt(option);

    QLabel *label = new QLabel;
    label->setText(index.data().toString());
    label->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
    label->setGeometry(option.rect);
    label->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : transparent; }");

    painter->translate(option.rect.topLeft());
    label->render(painter);
    painter->translate(-option.rect.topLeft());
}
```

Но это только рисует ссылку и не более.

Чтобы сделать ссылку кликабельной нужно переписать метод `setModel` из `table/list view` и использовать `setIndexWidget`.

```
    void MyView::setModel(QAbstractItemModel *m)
    {
        if(!m) return;

        QTableView::setModel(m);

        const int rows = model()->rowCount();
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        {
           QModelIndex idx = model()->index(i, 5);

           label=new QLabel(model()->data(idx,Qt::DisplayRole).toString());
           label->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
           //label->setText(model()->data(idx,Qt::DisplayRole).toString());
           //label->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
           connect( label, SIGNAL(linkActivated(QString)), this, SLOT(onLabelLinkClicked(QString)));
           setIndexWidget(idx, label);
        }

    }

    void MyView::onLabelLinkClicked(QString link)
    {
          QUrl url = QUrl::fromUserInput(link);
          if(url.isValid())
              QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);
    }
```

В примере выше `столбцы 1` заменены на `QLabel`. Обратите внимание, что вам необходимо изменить `display role` в модели, чтобы избежать повторения данных.

*© Вольный перевод [ответа на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20566976/)*.

---

> **Дополнение от 25.05.2018:**
>
> Скорее всего под изменением `display role` имелась ввиду
>   `CTableModel::HtmlRole`.  И поэтому я думаю, что строку:
>
> `label->setText(model()->data(idx, CTableModel::HtmlRole).toString());`
>
> надо заменить на:
>
> `label->setText(model()->data(idx, Qt::DisplayRole).toString());`
>
> либо на какую-то `display role`из представленных в
>   [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum).
>
> Также важно посмотреть [документацию функции «data» класса
>   «QAbstractItemModel»](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data).

---

Помимо этого вы можете поискать в поисковике на английском языке:

- "[how to add link to file in QTableView](https://google.ru/search?client=opera&q=how%20to%20add%20link%20to%20file%20in%20QTableView)"
- "[how to add URL to QTableView](https://google.ru/search?q=how%20to%20add%20URL%20to%20QTableView)"

Возможно, нужный вам ответ вы найдёте в ответах на вопросы на англоязычном SO:

- [How to provide multiple links in one cell of a QTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31563699/) (Как добавить несколько ссылок в ячейки QTableView)
- [How do I use QDesktopServices::openUrl with 'file:' URL containing '#'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31563699/) (Как использовать `QDesktopServices::openUrl` с `file:` со ссылкой-якорем)

Comment: Можно добавить что будет возможность отловить клик по ячейке QTableView и вытащить значение из ячейки, а после применить `QDesktopServices::openURL()` чтобы открыть файл

Comment: У меня ругается на CTableModel::HtmlRole  'CTableModel' has not been declared

Comment: Что за модель CTableModel ?

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, я указал в ответе, что это вольный перевод ответа на enSO. Ссылку на него я тоже там привёл. Сам я, к сожалению, не знаю, что это за CTableModel::HtmlRole.

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, по ссылке, что я дал есть и [другой ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35868735/). Обратите там внимание на `QVariant value = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole)`. Согласно документации [QAbstractItemModel::data](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) во втором параметре ожидается `int role = Qt::DisplayRole`.

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, также в ответе моём написано: Обратите внимание, что вам необходимо изменить `display role` в модели, чтобы избежать повторения данных.

Comment: Это не совсем то что я ожидал увидеть. Я видел этот пост и до этого. У меня получилось сделать то что я хочу, но у меня дублируется данные и что такое display role я так и не понял. Я попробую позже сделать с помощью делегатов и поправлю этот ответ

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, я думаю, что `display role` - это `Qt::DisplayRole`, т. е то, что ожидается на входе в функции `data` класса `QAbstractItemModel`, о чём я писал в [моём отзыве выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/817736/#comment1329400_831618). Другими словами: `CTableModel::HtmlRole` надо заменить на к примеру `Qt::DisplayRole`.

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, я написал дополнение в ответе.

Comment: @Bharata Я отмечу этот ответ, как правильный . Но у меня по прежнему дублируются данные Qt::DisplayRole не помогает и многие другие роли тоже, которые я попробовал подставить. То что я пробовал подставить убирает ссылки или дублирует запись. Например роль  Qt::ItemDataRole() , также отображает данные как и Qt::DisplayRole

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, но ссылки теперь при каком-то условии всё же работают?

Comment: @Bharata Да но там еще надо добавить кое что . Чтоб ссылка открывалась. Сейчас изменю ответ твой

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77982/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-bharata).